# Binance platform trustability

Tags: wallet, trading, investing, binance

What is the current state of major trading platforms (to be more precise, Binance)? I have read numerous bad things about both Binance and Coinbase (such as Binance being banned by MasterCard and Maestro, people not able to withdraw from Binance account, Coinbase being reported as non-legit website on many VPN providers...). It would be nice if someone could speak up based on personal experience. My opinion is mainly biased due to this [review](https://99bitcoins.com/bitcoin-exchanges/binance-review/). It seems like a legit website, but the comments below do not, at least not all of them. Anyways I don't see a point of fake flaming Binance on some third-party website, and that is exactly what confuses me.

Comment: Use Bisq: https://bisq.wiki/Main_Page

Comment: @Prayank would you mind argumenting?